# when user using Atlassian account password for basic authentication to connect to bitbucket cloud

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

> If you are using the HTTPS protocol for Git operations

> And when user cloning any repo so basically showing this are the error show => :

```
Cloning into 'demorepo'…

Password for 'https://rmakwanakrishnainfotechsoftware@bitbucket.org': ****

remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.

remote: App passwords are recommended for most use cases and can be created in your Personal settings:

remote: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/

fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/rmakwanakrishnainfotechsoftware//demorepo.git/'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**. First Log in using your Atlassian account password for Basic authentication to connect to Bitbucket Cloud

click on link => https://id.atlassian.com/signup?application=bitbucket&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org%2Faccount%2Fsignin%2F%3Fnext%3D%252F

**Step 2**. Then you will need to update your configuration to use either an app password.

Go to the profile account and click on Personal settings

**Step 3**. In your Personal Settings you will be show App password.

Click on App password

**Step 4**. so here basically you can create your App password

Click on Create app password , so here you see some check box.
check box click based on your requirement

**Step 5**. click on Create button so code will be generate automatically.
please copy that code because, clone any repo time use this password.

so now on word your issue will resolved.

**Thankyou team**

**Happy coding**,